# DNN DAL2 Error in Create, Update, Delete ... Gets work just fine

Tags: vb.net, dotnetnuke

I am having trouble with a DNN DAL2 module written in VB.  This is a DNN 7.3.2 install.

The module's Get methods work just fine, but the Create, Update and Delete methods throw errors like this:

```
    DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

    at DotNetNuke.Data.RepositoryBase`1.GetPropertyValue[TProperty](T item, String propertyName) 
    at DotNetNuke.Data.RepositoryBase`1.GetScopeValue[TProperty](T item) 
    at DotNetNuke.Data.RepositoryBase`1.ClearCache(T item) 
    at DotNetNuke.Data.RepositoryBase`1.Update(T item) 
    at TAC.DNN.Modules.TAC_NPIDal2.Components.ForumReadController.UpdateForumRead(ForumRead t) in D:\Websites\npi1-2017\DesktopModules\TAC_NPIDal2\Components\ForumReadController.vb:line 79 
    at TAC.DNN.Modules.TAC_NPIForum.Thread.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Websites\npi1-2017\DesktopModules\TAC_NPIForum\Thread.ascx.vb:line 121 

The Forum class is defined like this:

<TableName("NPIForum_Read")>
<PrimaryKey("ID", AutoIncrement:=True)>
<Cacheable("NPIForumRead", CacheItemPriority.Default, 20)>
<Scope("ForumID")>
Public Class ForumRead

    Private _ID As Integer
    Private _userID As Integer
    Private _forumID As Integer
    Private _threadID As Integer
    Private _lastViewed As DateTime
```

(and with appropriate Gets and Sets)

```
And the UpdateForumRead method is defined like this:

        Public Sub UpdateForumRead(ByVal t As ForumRead)

            Using ctx As IDataContext = DataContext.Instance()
                Dim rep As IRepository(Of ForumRead) = ctx.GetRepository(Of ForumRead)()
                rep.Update(t)
            End Using
        End Sub
```

---

Now, the database is actually updated.  The SQL code that is generated runs without and error, and the ForumThreads table gets updated.  The error occurs this.  When single stepping, the exception is thrown on the "End Using" statement.  Also, the t object is ok, and has no problems.

Any ideas on this one?

Thanks

Comment: Joe, what is the exception text that you see when stepping through it?

Comment: Scott, It is the standard "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. And it occurs after the sql is executed.

Comment: I should add that I'm working on updating a set of modules, basically converting to Dal2.  Other modules work completely.  So, there's something "different" happening here.

Comment: Perhaps on the update, the ForumID attribute in the ForumRead object is null?  That may still allow the update to work, but to refresh the cache that is scoped by the ForumID may fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is after the update when DAL2 tries to invalidate the cache.

Two possible issues:

1. The newly inserted record (or possible existing records in the table have a NULL ForumID.  Since you indicated this is the Scope field, it needs to be NOT NULL in the table and should have a value.
2. Your primary key, ID, is not setup as an Identity in the database?  You indicated on your DAL model class that it is an autoincrement, so DAL2/Petapoco is going to assume the database will generate it.

Comment: Scott, The table is defined as 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NPIForum_Read]( 
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[userID] [int] NOT NULL, 
[forumID] [int] NOT NULL, 
[threadID] [int] NOT NULL, 
[lastViewed] [datetime] NOT NULL, 

CONSTRAINT [PK_NPIForum_Read] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY] 

There are no NULLs.

Comment: Do your public class attributes exactly match your table column names?

Comment: Scott,

The last simple question is the key!

It turns out that the case of the text string in the <Scope ...> needs to match the class property exactly!

Wow!  (and a giant thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

See my last reply to Scott.  That's the answer!